# Several ggplots plots with different heights and widths wrapped in function

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

Apologies, this is not a fully reproducible example but should hopefully convey the gist of my problem using the current approach. I (try to) use the following code in a Jupyter notebook to print several graphs with different sizes:

```
#reporducible data
temp <- mtcars[, 1:3]
colnames(temp) <- c("x1", "z", "y1")

plotting_function <- function(data_to_vis) {
  
  options(repr.plot.width = 5, repr.plot.height = 5) 
  p1 <- ggplot(data_to_vis, aes(x=x1, y=y1)) +
    geom_point(size = 3)         
  print(p1)
  
  options(repr.plot.width = 20, repr.plot.height = 20) 
  p2 <- ggplot(data_to_vis, aes(x=x1, y=y1)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~z) +
    theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
  print(p2)
}

library(ggplot2)
plotting_function(temp)
```

Using:

```
options(repr.plot.width = 5, repr.plot.height = 5)
```

usually works fine but not in this use case - it is not adhered to - the first graph p1 is printed using:

```
options(repr.plot.width = 20, repr.plot.height = 20)
```

Maybe there is a better approach for this use case?

Comment: Please add minimal code to make it a full reprex.

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe merge the plots using, for example, {patchwork}, then you would have more control over layout?

Comment: @user2554330 added repro.

Comment: appreciated @zx8754!

Comment: I'm not using Jupyter either so my comment might be completely off - If you don't necessarily need to use that function, then in RMarkdown I'd just use a new code chunk with different figure options for the second figure. If you need that function, then I guess that zx8754's suggestion should be a very good solution.

Comment: patchwork seems to work fine.

Comment: I hope you or @zx8754 will write that up as an answer.  In the meantime, I've concluded that Jupyter has a bug, and put a workaround into my answer, but if they fix the bug my answer will no longer work.

Comment: Feel free to post patchwork solution as an answer by yourself, I can’t post at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Jupyter, so I experimented with https://jupyter.org/try
to come up with this "solution".  I can't explain it, but to me it certainly looks like a bug.

The problem is that `options()` settings aren't handled in the expected order.  The options you set apply to the **previous** plot.  So this simple change to your script worked for me:

```r
temp <- mtcars[, 1:3]
colnames(temp) <- c("x1", "z", "y1")

plotting_function <- function(data_to_vis) {
  
  p1 <- ggplot(data_to_vis, aes(x=x1, y=y1)) +
    geom_point(size = 3)         
  print(p1)
  options(repr.plot.width = 5, repr.plot.height = 5) 

  p2 <- ggplot(data_to_vis, aes(x=x1, y=y1)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~z) +
    theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
  print(p2)
  options(repr.plot.width = 20, repr.plot.height = 20) 
  
}

library(ggplot2)
plotting_function(temp)
```

You can also move the first `options()` setting before printing `p1`, but you can't move the second one before printing `p2`, or it will also apply to `p1`.

Bug?  Looks like it to me.

Comment: thanks. good to know and I would not have thought of that!